# New questions displayed offset to existing ones when using "new activity" link

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

This may be a "feature" but I've noticed today that when clicking the `xx questions with new activity` link at the top of the list of questions in a particular tag, the new questions loaded are now displayed offset to the old ones. For example, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?tab=Newest before clicking the link:

[image]

and afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate on MSE: [Incorrect indentation for questions loaded via AJAX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361403/incorrect-indentation-for-questions-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: [More details here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405693/the-layout-gets-messed-up-when-new-questions-are-loaded-via-ajax)