# The layout gets messed up when new questions are loaded via ajax

Tags: bug, design

[image]

The original questions seem to have the following HTML format:

```
<div class="mln24">
    <div class="question-summary" id="question-summary-66433415">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Whereas the asynchronously loaded questions are missing the wrapping `mln24` element, and have gained a `style="display: flex;"` attribute:

```
<div class="question-summary" id="question-summary-66433774" style="display: flex;">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[Full HTML of questions section (on pastebin to keep this question short).](https://pastebin.com/irDEYQdH)